# Firebase Data Download Size

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been making an ionic app with Firebase but I have a general question.

if I have the database like this:

```
profile:
{
  101: 
  {
     name: jon
     lastname: snow
     ...
     reservations:
       {
         ..lot of data
       }
     requests:
       {
        ..lot of data
       }
  }
}
```

If I call from my app services :

```
firebase.database().ref('/profile/101/reservations).once('value') ...
```

does it download the whole profile data? because I am concerned about the data usage for the future.
Also because I know that if I call only

```
firebase.database().ref('/profile/101').once('value') ...
```

It will download the whole data. I am just concerned if for the first case, it will be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attach a listener to a location ([`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#reference)) (that you have permission to read) in the Firebase Database, it downloads all the data under that location.

When you attach a listener to a query ([`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#query)) in a location (that you have permission to read), it downloads all data under the location that matches the query.

Comment: Ok Thanks so when i attach to reservations reference it will only download the references data

Answer (score 1):

That's why you have to change your structure to :

```
profile:
{
  101: 
  {
     name: jon
     lastname: snow
     ...
     reservations: [801,...],
     requests:[....]
  }
},
reservations:{
    801:{
          profileId:101,
         ..lot of data
    },
    ....
},
requests:{
.....
}
```

Comment: my question is if I call firebase.database().ref('/profile/101/reservations).once('value'), does firebase download the requests ?